# Can I still use the App Store with a development iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone

I can't seem to find any help when I search via Google, so I guess it's time to ask the experts directly!

I've got an iPod Touch which I'm using as a development device for an application that I'm producing. The first thing I did with my iPod Touch was connect it up and install my app.

But when I try and install downloaded apps from the App Store, iTunes won't let me drag them onto the device. The first time I tried a popup did appear but I accidentally closed it before I read it, and I can't get it to reappear, as I'm sure it had some useful info.

Does anyone know the deal? Are development devices exclusive to your own signed apps?

Many thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not for exclusive development use, you can still do everything you like with your iPod Touch.

Note however that some applications can have device restrictions on them.  That means they'll only be syncable to certain devices.  If an application has a device restriction set to iPhone, it won't sync to your iPod Touch.

I guess make sure that application syncing is enabled in iTunes and the applications you want to put on the device are selected (or All Applications is).

Answer (score 1):

No. They're not. I use mi iPod Touch as a development, music listening AND new apps from AppStore device. All at the same time. The same thing goes for iPhone.